# RadRails: An internal error occurred during: "Starting Server"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse

I've decided to learn some Ruby on Rails, but unfortunately I can't get the testing server to work. When I try to fire it up I get this message: **RadRails: An internal error occurred during: "Starting Server"**, and when I click OK in the message window the server's status is frozen at **Starting**. I get no other errors or messages.

I use the RadRails - EasyEclipse for Ruby and Rails IDE (latest version as far as I'm concerned) and I've followed these instructions to set everyting up: http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/distributions/ruby-rails.html.
The Apache server is up and running when I click the **Manage Servers**-tab in **Bitnami Ruby Stack**

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting without even commenting a reason for it, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have Rails set up, try starting WEBrick from the command line. `cd` to your_app_directory and try `rails s`. This will at least help you isolate the issue to your Rails installation vs your dev tools.